# Mostrar solo una vez las condiciones de un foreach

Tags: php

Tengo la siguiente cadena:

```
$cadena = "lucia,carolina,roberto,carlos,carolinaramos";
$datos = explode(",", $cadena);
```

Y uso este método para condicionar:

```
$idUsuario = "carolina";
foreach ($cadena as $nombre_campo) {
    if ($nombre_campo != $idUsuario) {
        echo "No estas en el grupo";
    }
    else{ echo "Ya estás en este grupo"; }
}
```

El problema está en que si hay 5 palabaras en la cadena, **5 veces va a mostrar los mensajes**.

Lo que necesito es que si No está su usuario en esa cadena muestre solo una vez "**No estas en el grupo**" y sino "**Ya estás en este grupo**"
Agradezco sus respuestas, si hay una **forma de hacer más efectivo este proceso** haganmelo saber, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, me parece que está mal formulada tu pregunta por que en $cadena estas pasando 5 datos, el foreach esta echo en base a $Cadena

Comment: Por lo tanto te va a contar cada palabra despues de cada ,

Comment: @Roderick De acuerdo amigo, conoces algún método que cumpla con lo qu equiero lograr? he estado buscando y no encuentro nada.

Comment: $cadena = $idUsuario;
$datos = explode(",", $cadena);
Y uso este método para condicionar:

$idUsuario = "carolina";
foreach ($cadena as $nombre_campo) {
    if ($nombre_campo != $idUsuario) {
        echo "No estas en el grupo";
    }
    else{ echo "Ya estás en este grupo"; }
}

Comment: Este tipo de algoritmos se suelen solucionar con una bandera que inicializas a false, luego en el bucle, si se cumple la condición, la pones a tejer y terminas el bucle con un break. Una vez fuera del bucle analiza la variable. Si es false, escribe el mensaje de no estar en el grupo. Si es true, escribe que lo está.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Con una variable inicializada `false` y dentro del bucle igualarla a `true` en caso de coincidir con `$idUsuario` podrías después fuera del bucle imprimir un frase u otra dependiendo de lo que contenga esa variable booleana.

```
$cadena = "lucia,carolina,roberto,carlos,carolinaramos";
$datos = explode(",", $cadena);
$idUsuario = "carolina";
$encontrado = false;

foreach ($datos as $nombre_campo) {
    if ($nombre_campo == $idUsuario) {
       $encontrado = true;
    }
}

if ($encontrado) {
    echo 'Estás en el grupo';
}
else {
    echo 'No estás en el grupo';    
}
```

O bien podrías usar `in_array()` una función específica de **PHP** que pasándole un valor que buscar  y un `array` donde hacerlo, te devuelve `true` o `false` dependiendo de si encuentra dicho valor o no:

```
$cadena = "lucia,carolina,roberto,carlos,carolinaramos";
$datos = explode(",", $cadena);
$idUsuario = "carolina";

if (in_array($idUsuario, $datos)) {
    echo 'Estás en el grupo';
}
else {
    echo 'No estás en el grupo';    
}
```

Comment: No sabes cuanto te lo agradezco! Era justo lo que necesitaba.